# Em associações no CakePHP, como alterar a chave de relacionamento?

Tags: php, cakephp

Em associações no CakePHP por padrão ele sempre faz o relacionamento sendo o nome do modelo no singular seguido de _id, ou seja, model_id.

É possível alterar essa chave de relacionamento para outro campo da tabela?

Tentei utilizar `foreignKey` mas não funcionou.

Abaixo os dois models:

```
<?php
class Cart_item extends AppModel 
{
    public $name = 'Cart_item';         
}
?>
```

E Cart:

```
<?php
class Cart extends AppModel 
{
    public $name = 'Cart';      
    public $hasMany = array(
            'Cart_item' => array(
                'className' => 'Cart_item',
                'foreignKey' => 'Cart_uid'
            )
        );      
}
?>
```

Comment: `foreignKey` deveria funcionar. Essa é a maneira de fazer isso mesmo. Posta o seu codigo pra ver se não tem algum outro erro

Answer (score 1):

Certifique-se que não está confundindo o que deve aparecer na foreignKey. 
Como mostra o manual do cake, no model deve estar deste modo:

```
class Profile extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez haja um erro na linha

```
 'foreignKey' => 'Cart_uid',
```

Possivelmente seria

```
'foreignKey' => 'Cart_id',
```